# Catch exception in another thread c#

Tags: c#, exception

I write a simple program that used external dll
when I call a function of that dll, dll run a thread
then function passed succesfully
but after while thread cause exception and program closed
I want to now how to handle this bug so my program can continue work

Answer (score 5):

You can create an event handler for unhandled exceptions in a given app domain

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.71).aspx

If nothing else handles the Exception, that event handler will be invoked.

Comment: Hi thanxs for answer but after unhandledexception event fire application will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what releases the exception and then you should work on preventing it. You can disassamble the dll with http://www.reflector.net to view the code inside the dll.

Comment: thanx I know  where exception is occurre but I cant handle it.